# how to make directive in angular of owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

can you please tell me how to make dirctive in angular js .I need to use owl carousel plugin in js as I did in jqm fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o9foej5L/1/
.I need to make same thing in angular using directive can you please tell me how I will implement this using directive 
http://plnkr.co/edit/4ySYwsqrBKUJUj6MwoRY?p=catalogue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" />
     <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="   http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" />

    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div id="owl-demo">
 <div class="item"><p>one</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>two</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>three</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>four</p></div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a directive like this:

```
app.directive('owlCarousel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      owlOptions: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).owlCarousel(scope.owlOptions);
    }
  };
});
```

And on the HTML add it as an attribute:

```
<div owl-carousel owl-options="owlOptions">
  ...
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/n1AdIdflOUX3ZMie8mwb?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is my general solution. This works with ngrepeat and with refresh data of the scope. The trick is add a directive for the last item, so the init will be fired when the last item is in the dom.

```
<div owl-slides-count="3" owl-carousel="">
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts" owl-carousel-item="">
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

... the js

```
.directive('owlCarousel', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.initCarousel = function () {
                    // hacky ondomready
                    $timeout(function hackyDomReady() {
                        // if is already initialized destroy and re create it
                        // $(element).data().owlCarousel <- owl 2
                        if ($(element).data('owlCarousel')) { // <- owl 1
                            // $(element).trigger('destroy.owl.carousel'); // <- owl 2
                            $(element).data('owlCarousel').destroy();// <- owl 1
                        }

                        $(element).owlCarousel({
                            autoPlay: 10000,
                            navigation: true,
                            items: attrs.owlSlidesCount
                        });
                    });
                };
            }
        };
    }])

    .directive('owlCarouselItem', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: false,
            link: function (scope, element) {
                if (scope.$last) {
                    scope.initCarousel();
                }
            }
        };
    }])
```