# Combining JQuery owl-carousel with Angular single page application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to have a JQuery owl-carousel object inside my angular js single page application.

this is the code in angular:

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <title>Small Talkz</title>
 <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="small-talkz.model.js"></script>
    <script src="components/chat/chatController.js"></script>
    <script src="components/login/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/jumbotron.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/owl.theme.css">

 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-app="smallTalkzModel" class="loader">
        <div ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is where angular routing takes place:

small-talkz.model.js

```
var smallTalkzModel = angular.module('smallTalkzModel', ['ui.router']);
smallTalkzModel.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl : 'components/login/loginView.html',
    controller  : 'loginController'
  }) 
  .state('chat', {
    url: '/chat',
    templateUrl : 'components/chat/chatView.html',
    controller  : 'chatController'
  })
  .state('carousel', {
    url: '/carousel',
    templateUrl : 'components/carousel/carouselView.html',
    controller  : 'carouselController'
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

and this is the carouselView.html

```
<body>
<div id="carousel_demo">
    <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
      <div> Content1 </div>
      <div> Content2 </div>
      <div> Content3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is the carouselController.js

```
smallTalkzModel.controller('carouselController', ['$scope', 
  function($scope){ 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
    });
  }]);
```

but when I enter into the page (localhost:3000/#/carousel) I don't see anything.

I don't even get an error on chrome developer's tools console (F12).

I think there is something wrong with the combination of JQuery  $(document).ready(..) and angular bootstraping but I am not sure what is the problem...

please help me figure it out.

Comment: [take a look at this answer too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396287/3744400) is my generic solution for owl directive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make directive in angular of owl carousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686700/how-to-make-directive-in-angular-of-owl-carousel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery from inside the angular.

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
})
```

Comment: thanks I did it but now it just shows me the "Content1", "Content2", "Content3", without the owlCarousel behavior (just plain text). where do I need to put my css?

Comment: you should put css in the head is usual, do got the jquery behavior is it should be ?

Comment: No. :( Are you sure that it is ok to put jqeury code ($(document).ready(....)) inside angular js controller?

Comment: in a last project is was same we couldn't execute jquery from outside angular but from inside. i'm pretty sure..

Comment: @Matoy you can try to use $rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
   $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
});

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following code

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller('owlController', owlController);

function owlController() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(#owl-example).owlCarousel({
      items : 3,
      itemsCustom : false,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,2],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [980,2],
      itemsTablet: [768,2],
      itemsTabletSmall: [767,1],
      itemsMobile : [479,1],
      singleItem : false,
      itemsScaleUp : false,
      navigation : true,
      navigationText : ["",""],
      pagination : false
    });
  }, 0);
}
```

and in template do

```
<div id="carousel_demo"  ng-controller="owlController">
    <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
      <div> Content1 </div>
      <div> Content2 </div>
      <div> Content3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```